# LED organ input problem

Tags: led, operational-amplifier

I'd made this LED organ (schematic below and [here](http://cdn.makezine.com/make/blogs/blog.makezine.com/ledColorOrgan-schem_r1.gif)):

[image: Schematics]

And one of the filters are not working. On the opamp's inverting input, there's a small sin signal, and I don't know where it comes from.

I measured these with my scope on the filter. This is the (audio) input signal from the function generator:

[image: This is the (audio) input signal from the function generator]

This is the output one of the filters:

[image: This is the output one of the filter]

This is on the inverting input of the opamp without an audio input signal:

[image: This is on the inverting input of the opamp without an audio input signal]

I don't know which component is causing this. I replaced the opamp IC and the transistors are working too, but I get the same problem.

Comment: "*On the opamp's inverting input*" There are 5 op amps shown in the diagram and three filters, that would give a 1 in 3 chance of guessing where this signal is actually located.

Comment: It's a quad op amp.

Comment: @Passerby I can see that by the IC ref markings but regardless of the package - there are still three filter circuits (hence the one in three chance). I'm just trying to locate exactly where the measurements are taken from and I still can't tell as it it not specified which filter is not working in the question.

Comment: Sorry, its IC1B

Comment: I also think bass and treble filters are incorrectly named.

Comment: Maybe bad caps or a bad pot? Have you tried rebuilding the bass stage with all new passive just to test?

Comment: @Andyaka *"I also think bass and treble filters are incorrectly named"*  I don't believe so.  I built this same circuit six months ago (it's a [kit from Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2155541_-1)) and mine works fine -- yellow channel is treble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the virtual ground is stable, then double check all the capacitor and resistor *values* (and presence) in the affected filter.

I suspect that one or more is off by 10:1 or something like that. If the 680 ohm resistors have 3-digit markings, they should be 681 not 680.

Comment: How do you check for the stability of virtual ground, and how do you correct it?

Comment: @Sada93 He has a real (Instek) oscilloscope- so he can just look at the voltage. If there is something wrong the cure would depend on the cause, but there's no point in checking other stuff if the power supplies are not stable.

Comment: The virtual ground avg is around 4.12V, and the values are ok too.